# Redefining a jQuery dialog button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In our application we use a general function to create jQuery dialogs which contain module-specific content. The custom dialog consists of 3 buttons (Cancel, Save, Apply). Apply does the same as Save but also closes the dialog.

Many modules are still using a custom post instead of an ajax-post. For this reason I'm looking to overwrite/redefine the buttons which are on a specific dialog.

So far I've got the buttons, but I'm unable to do something with them. Is it possible to get the buttons from a dialog (yes, I know) but apply a different function to them?

My code so far:

```
function OverrideDialogButtonCallbacks(sDialogInstance) {
  oButtons = $( '#dialog' ).dialog( 'option', 'buttons' );
  console.log(oButtons); // logs the buttons correctly

  if(sDialogInstance == 'TestInstance') {
    oButtons.Save = function() {
      alert('A new callback has been assigned.');
      // code for ajax-post will come here.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: $('#dialog').dialog({
'buttons' : {
    'Save' : {
        click: function() {
           //
        },
    },
}
}); //tried this?

Comment: This works indeed. But now I have to redefine all the buttons (which is not a problem). Nevertheless I was wondering if it is possible to 'get' a button and apply a new callback function to it.

Comment: check the button id, and delegate a callback on click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
'buttons' : {
    'Save' : {
        id:"btn-save", // provide the id, if you want to apply a callback based on id selector
        click: function() {
           //
        },
    },
}
});
```

Did you try this? to override button's callback based on the need.

Comment: Re-assigning the entire buttons to the dialog seems the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: .map? `oButtons is not an array!

Comment: Naveen is correct. +1. in his answer he says you dont need re-assignging. You can follow the approach he stated.

Comment: yes OButtons is not an array. One cannot iterate it through map. i will update the answer. thnx

Comment: Somehow the callback function is executed at the time I open dialog box. jQuery 1.9 here.

Answer (score 2):

No need to re-assign at all. Try this.

```
function OverrideDialogButtonCallbacks(dialogSelector) {
    var button = $(dialogSelector + " ~ .ui-dialog-buttonpane")
                    .find("button:contains('Save')");

    button.unbind("click").on("click", function() {
        alert("save overriden!");
    });
}
```

Call it like `OverrideDialogButtonCallbacks("#dialog");`

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/yzfVT/

Answer (score 1):

You can get the buttons using `$(..).dialog('option', 'buttons')`. This returns an array of objects that you can then rewire by searching through them and adjusting the click event:

```
// Rewire the callback for the first button
var buttons = $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'buttons');
buttons[0].click = function() { alert('Click rewired!'); };
```

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/z4TTH/2/

If necessary, you can check the text of the button using `button[i].text`.

---

**UPDATE:**

The `buttons` option can be one of two forms, one is an array as described above, the other is an object where each property is the name of the button. To rewire the click event in this instance it's necessary to update the `buttons` option in the dialog:

```
// Rewire the callback for the OK button
var buttons = $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'buttons');
buttons.Ok = function() { alert('Click rewired!'); };

$('#dialog').dialog('option', 'buttons', buttons);
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z4TTH/3/

Comment: Your first option isn't working in my set-up. The second option adds another Save button ;) Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try binding your new function code with Click event of Save?

```
if(sDialogInstance == 'TestInstance') {
            $('#'+savebtn_id).click(function() {
              alert('A new callback has been assigned.');
              // code for ajax-post will come here.
            });
    }
```

Comment: For some reason the id can't be found (while it is applied to the button, so this isn't working for me). Thanks for your input.

Comment: Make sure the component is loaded before you refer it.